# How to move items in listbox to its original position

Tags: sapui5, listitem

I have a listbox with several listitems, I post one for example:

```
var listboxChooseColumns = new sap.ui.commons.ListBox("chooseColumns", {
    allowMultiSelect: true,
    items: [
        nameItem,
        new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
            text: "Functional Location",
            test: "lastName"   
        })
    ]
})
```

The listitems from one box can be moved to another one:

```
var moveAllToTableColumn = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
        press: function() {
            //var selectedItems = listboxChooseColumns.getSelectedItems();
            var selectedItems = listboxChooseColumns.getItems();
            for (var i=0; i<selectedItems.length;i++) {
                var listItem = selectedItems[i];
                listBoxChosenColumns.addItem(listItem);   
            }
        }
});
```

If I want to bring the item back from the second list to the first one, the item goes to the end of the list, not in its initial position.

```
var moveFromTableColumn = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
    press: function(){
        var selectedItems = listBoxChosenColumns.getSelectedItems();
        for (var i=0; i<selectedItems.length;i++) {
            var listItem = selectedItems[i];
            listBoxChosenColumns.removeItem(listItem);
            listboxChooseColumns.addItem(listItem);   
        }
    }
});
```

How can I return item from the second list to the first list into initial position?

Comment: Please consider formatting your code in future questions, so it's readable. Thanks.

Comment: yes, i will do. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of addItem(), consider using [insertItem(oItem, iIndex)](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.ListBox.html#insertItem) which allows you to position the item being inserted (e.g. at the top, if you specify 0 for iIndex):

```
listboxChooseColumns.insertItem(listItem, 0);
```

Comment: In addition, you could store the original index as a customData attribute of the ListItem. For example listItem.addCustomData(new sap.ui.core.CustomData({key:"org-index",value:2 });

Comment: Thanks you guys! i think i still didnt solve it. i added original index to list items:    new sap.ui.core.ListItem({                              }).addCustomData(new sap.ui.core.CustomData({key:"org-index",value:1 })),  and on buttons i used var initialIndex = new sap.ui.core.CustomData({key:"org-index",value: i });

Comment: then listBoxChosenColumns.insertItem(listItem, initialIndex);   and if i do the same to bring item in initial list to its position, it still appears in the end of the list...where i went wrong?

Comment: You asked "How can i return item from the second list to the first list into initial position?". My answer, showing "listboxChooseColumns.insertItem(listItem, 0)" does exactly that. Can you please explain why you unaccepted my answer?

Comment: @user3189516 in the button section, retrieve the list item and call listItem.getCustomData(). Then you can find the initial value of the index

Comment: dear qmarco, i did it purely my mistake, sorry. just clicked around."listboxChooseColumns.insertItem(listItem, 0)" did work, but the problem is: i have each time different ammount of list items (around 91) so i have to add index or smth in place of "0". i apologize if i ask qs not clear - i am 3 months in programming

Comment: clearify: i pick from list 1 items position 22, 33,44. so in list 2 they are on position 1,2,3. but i want to bring them back, they should be on 22, 33,44.